# Read/unread counter and list in Cordova application

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, listview

I develop one Cordova application where I need to add read/unread counter and list where data fetch from the server just like the example below.

[image]
[image]

Please help me or give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalStorage, when we read one text, -1 the count. Whenever new data is loaded, we will update localstorage value.

If ur using angular js, data will updated,when we change $scope.count.